# Sonar as a service on Windows 8 32bit

Tags: windows-services, sonarqube

I have been running Sonar successfully on Windows 8 32bit.  I tried to get it working as a Windows service but I got a 503.  From something I found on Google I am running it as 'Network Service' but still no luck.  Also, I don't know how I can see any logging of what is going on, C:\Program Files\sonar-3.4.1\logs doesn't show anything once the service has started.  Any help would be appreciated, I'm so close!

Answer (score 0):

Create a dedicated windows (administraton) user ( i.e. sonar / sonar )  for the Sonar service and start the service with that user.

Comment: I'll try this on Monday and mark the question as answered then if it works, thanks.

Comment: Sorry I haven't tried yet and I'm away until Tuesday so I won't be able to try until next week :(  I'll post as soon as I can.